# Read weight from Metler Toledo BC60 Network Enabled Weight Scale via PHP Sockets

Tags: php, sockets

I have a Metler Toledo BC60 Network Enabled Scale.
Its on my local network with a local IP address. I can ping it and connect to it via terminal on port 82. If I sent it a "W" and press enter I get a number returned from it that is the weight at that moment.

How can I access this weight via PHP for use in my application?

My thought was something like this, but Im not getting anything back:

```
<?php
// host and port to connect to
$host = "192.168.0.115";
$port = 82;

// connect to the port
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);

// if connection not successfull, display error
if (!$fp)
{
   die("no connection");
}
else
{
   // connection successfull
   fwrite($fp, "W\r\n"); //Request Weight 
   $got = fgets($fp);
   // display the data
   echo  $got;
   fclose($fp);
   die();
}
?>
```

Comment: That code looks ok to me. Check the return value of `fwrite()` to ensure it's not false. And do a `var_dump($got);` to see if you get empty string vs false.

Comment: You might also want to try `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Alex!    You got it!

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```

Did the trick!